# How to display an utf-8 character in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, text-rendering

Is there a way to render a tick mark using pygame? I tried using the unicode directly like this:

```
def write(screen, text, color, position, size):
    font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), size)# Defining a font with font and size
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)# Defining the text color which will be rendered
    screen.blit(text_surface, (position[0], position[1])) # Rendering the font

write(window, u'\u2713', self.color, position, size)
```

But this just draws a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'rectangle' that is being written is in fact the representation of the `✓` sign using a `pygame.font.get_default_font()`. In order to display a `✓` sign you need to be sure, that this sign is included in a font that you are using. I propose the following solution:

1. Download the font that includes this symbol (e.g. Segoe UI Symbols from [here](https://freefontsdownload.net/free-segoeuisymbol-font-135679.htm))
2. Unzip the font package into the data folder (or main applicaation folder)
3. Change the font that you are using to the downloaded one

```
    font = pygame.font.Font("seguisym.ttf", size)
```

4. Use a write function either using a `write(window, u'\u2713', self.color, position, size)` method or directly using `write(screen, "✓", self.color, position, size)`